# What's the normal water flow from a residential RO membrane?

Tags: water

I just replaced the filters of a reverse osmosis system by myself for the first time. However, I realized that the water flow from the outlet of the RO membrane is very low, like droplets.

Does anyone know if this is normal or is my OR membrane damaged? At this rate it will take forever for the tank to fill, and until then there's no water out from the tap :(

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Depending on your membranes gpm rating the flow is relativly slow also the reject side will be faster depending on its rejection ratio.  Most are 8 to 1. Good nembranes will be high gpd with a 2 to 1 ratio

Also these flow rates are if you dripped the product into a barrel. When you start adding back pressure. Like filling you tank. When it's half full you cut your production in half.  At 3/4 you cut another half.  Example.  50gpd becomes 25 at half full and 12.5 at 3/4.   Always go with the company with the biggest membranes and lowest rejection rates